# Ошибка С3779: функцию возвращающую decltype(auto) нельзя использовать, предварительно не определив

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, auto

```
#include<iostream>


template <typename T1>decltype(auto) name(const T1& a, const T1& b);
int main()
{
    int a{ 33 };
    int b{ 22 };
    name (a,b);
    
}
template <typename T1>
decltype(auto) name(const T1& a, const T1& b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Капитанский ответ - ошибка в том, что функцию возвращающую decltype(auto) нельзя использовать предварительно не определив.

Comment: А как компилятор, не видя тела функции, может определить ее возвращаемый тип?

Comment: то есть в функциях,возвращающих auto прототип функции не будет работать?